# How to set the GNU screen log file name non-interactively

Tags: logging, gnu-screen

I'm trying to parse the output of a screen session from a script.
The man page of screen says I can use the command `logfile`, but gives no indication of the syntax to use when I launch screen non-interactively.

I would like to do something like this:

```
screen -L -d -m executable.app
```

But instead of having the output written to `screenlog.0`, have it written to a file of my choice.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of to have a custom log filename is to create a temporary .screenrc, add `logfile <LOG-NAME>` to it and tell screen to use it. Like this:

```
cp ~/.screenrc /tmp/
echo "logfile CUSTOM_NAME" >> /tmp/.screenrc
screen -c /tmp/.screenrc -L -d -m <PROGRAM>
```

Comment: If this answer works for you mark it as accepted. If it doesn't provide more details so that we can work on a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following to start screen session with a specific logfile.

```
screen -dmS <sock_name> && \
screen -S <sock_name> -X logfile <logfile_name> && \
screen -S <sock_name> -X log
```

Description:

```
screen -dmS <sock_name>                         #Start detached screen session
screen -S <sock_name> -X logfile <logfile_name> #Use logfile command to set logging file
screen -S <sock_name> -X log                    #Use log command to start logging
```